# Symfony specific page cache setting

Tags: caching, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Is there a way to disable cache setting for a specific page only in Symfony? What would be the code for that. Thx

Comment: i'm using sf1.4, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your are using sf1.4, you can use `cache.yml` to manage what to put in your cache. I recommend you to [read this doc](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/12-Caching) (about sf1.2 but it's ok for 1.4).

You will see that you can enable disable cache, in your `apps/[app_name]/modules/[module_name]/config/cache.yml` like :

```
mypage:
  enabled:    off
```